# Integrating Alfresco with a PHP Zend Application

Tags: php, zend-framework, alfresco

We have a PHP Zend application that has its own concepts of Users, Groups, Permissions etc. We now want to store the documents, blog pages etc. created by users into Alfresco. Has someone done integration of Zend application with Alfresco? I know that there is REST API on top of Alfresco which I can use from the PHP application. But wanted to find out how easy it is do it and also if all the capabilities of Alfresco are exposed thru it or not?

Are there some plugins that can make this integration easier?

Thanks,
Gaurav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some experience working with Alfresco in a Zend Framework application.  One of our major pain points is that it can be dreadfully slow to retrieve items out of Alfresco.  We've had to rely heavily on multiple caching layers in order to compensate for it's speed.  We're on 3.4 enterprise.  There may have been some improvements in Alfresco 4.0, but I just wanted to pass on that it has been a pretty rocky experience. We're actually in the process of storing the Alfresco content in a NoSQL solution in order to retrieve faster.

I know of another large scale company that went that route and they just recently migrated away from Alfresco integration.

This is not to say that it can't be done, just wanted to pass along my experience for what it's worth.